# Persist Firebase Auth session in Google Workspace Add-on

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Google Sheets add-on that needs to interact with existing web-app. The app uses Firebase for authentication. Firebase is not available as an "Advanced Google Service" and there is no official library (as well as official docs advice against using libraries in an add-on), so I'm using @firebase/auth in the client-side code.

The code is simple and the same as I'm using in the web-app (without FirebaseUI, but I've tried it as well) and because add-ons cannot use cookies or localStorage`*`, the Firebase cannot persist a local session.

Within the add-on we can only use Google Script Properties service, so I'm looking *if there is a way to persist a session manually for the Firebase* (like provide own "Storage" implementation, I've just done this for another node package I use in the add-on).

The question is mostly about Firebase and environment with no cookies/localStorage but other storage, but I may be missing some other way to use Firebase Auth with script add-ons.
Thanks for you help.

Edited: removed indexedDB, I've checked it in Console and accidentally switched from iframe to the top context, of course indexedDB is also unavailable in iframe (we should be sure the add-on works in Chrome).

---

`*` yes, we can ask user to go to the Chrome settings and select "Allow all cookies" but this is not an option for production.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any documented way to control the storage that Firebase Authentication beyond the picking from the options mentioned in the documentation on [auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).

I think allowing you to provide a custom storage implementation would be a valid feature request, so I recommend asking for it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/discussions). I don't think the request comes up frequently though, so it may not get the priority you'd like. In that case: implementing the feature would require allowing the developer to specify their own storage in the public SDK, and then you in your project implementing your own storage provider similar to the [storage providers in the SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/2901ed05e946d7010443fd3fa48b4aa3395e5463/packages-exp/auth-exp/src/platform_browser/persistence).

Comment: Thanks, at least this means I've got the auth state persistence doc correctly. In this case I probably need to use a custom token to reauthenticate an user.

Comment: p.s. It looks like I don't have enough rep for +1. So, thanks again!